# Unable to Pass Anonymous Object as additionalViewData When Using DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

According to Microsoft's [documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29), I should be able to pass an anonymously typed object as additionalViewData when calling @Html.DisplayFor; however, when I do this, I receive a yellow screen stating:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Surveys2.Models.ReportingSidebarItemViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Surveys2.Models.ReportingSidebarItemViewModel'.

Here is part of my view:

```
@model Surveys2.Models.ReportingPageViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pages, "ReportingSidebarItemViewModel", new { PageType = Model.PageType } )
```

Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult Summary(string projectCode)
{
ReportingPageViewModel reportingPageViewModel = GetReportingPageViewModel(new ReportingPageParams { ProjectCode = projectCode });
return View("Page", reportingPageViewModel);
}
```

Comment: error is self explanatory, you are passing list while the view needs single object as it is strongly typed to single object

Comment: But when I call using only a single parameter I don't receive an error:  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pages) even though the first parameters is the same for both overloads.

Comment: can you show your view's top part and your controller action code?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're targeting the display page by using the second param of DisplayFor. When you call displayfor(m=> m.prop) without a target view the ViewEngineCollection looks for the best suited diplay page. When the best suited display page is only for a single item and you passed a list it will iterate for you. The targeted display for assumes you are passing the exact type of the page you are targeting and thus it breaks.

EDIT-- Interestingly enough the MSDN Docs don't talk about looping except on the DisplayFor(m=> m.prop) method

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then both @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Questions) and @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pages, "ReportingSidebarItemViewModel", new { PageType = Model.PageType } ) would break the DisplayFor method, so why does only the latter of the two break while Razor has no problem with the first DisplayFor?

Comment: No Just DisplayFor(m=> m.prop) uses a runtime engine to figure out the most suited view and will execute the foreach if needed to make it work, But when you target the view by name it sends the property straight. Though I will admit that MSDN's docs don't differentiate. This has been my experience previously when dealing with DisplayFor

Comment: That did the trick! When I changed it to @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pages, new { PageType = Model.PageType }) and omitted the templateName I achieved the desired result.